# late construction within constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

I have two classes, one within the other and I want to construct the inner class in the main body of the outer class constructor. I have what I think should be the right code, but it's not working. The error message seems to be telling me that there is no VSL::VSL() matching my call, but it appears to be the correct prototype.

The code looks something like this:

in header:

```
class VSL
{
    VSL(vector<string> &v, string &s);
};
class KVTest
{
    VSL vsl;
    KVTest(int argc, char *argv[]);
};
```

in body:

```
KVTest::KVTest(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    vector<string> v;
    string s;

    vsl(v, s);
}
```

This fails with the following error message:

```
src/util/kv-test/kv-test.cpp: In constructor 'KVTest::KVTest(int, char**)':
src/util/kv-test/kv-test.cpp:237: error: no matching function for call to 'VSL::VSL()'
src/util/kv-test/kv-test.cpp:112: note: candidates are: VSL::VSL(std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >&, std::string&)
src/util/kv-test/kv-test.h:45: note:                 VSL::VSL(const VSL&)
src/util/kv-test/kv-test.cpp:347: error: no match for call to '(VSL) (std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::allocator<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > >&, std::string&)'
```

line 237 is the KVTest constructor declaration
line 347 is the line in that constructor where the vsl constructor is called
line 112 is the VSL constructor declaration
line 45 of the header is the { starting the VSL class
I do not have an explicit copy constructor for VSL

Comment: All constructs and variables in this example are private. Is that the issue?

Answer (score 3):

By the time you get inside the body of `KVTest::KVTest`, `vsl` has already been initialized; you can't call the constructor again.  But there is no default (i.e. zero-argument) constructor, hence the compiler error message.

You have two options:

1. Declare a default constructor for `VSL`.
2. Explicitly initialise `vsl` using the [constructor initialisation list](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.6).  That would typically look something like this:

   ```
   KVTest::KVTest(int argc, char *argv[])
   : vsl(foo, bar)
   {}
   ```

   If you need to perform complicated initialisation involving temporary variables, etc., then you should consider writing a private helper function that returns a `VSL`.

Answer (score 1):

First, it's not an "inner class" it's a data member.

Now compare your code to declaring and initializing an `int`:

```
int i = 0;
```

you can't create an `int` by writing:

```
i(0);
```

And similarly, this does not construct `vsl`:

```
vsl(v, s);
```

It's already constructed at that point, it gets constructed before body of the constructor starts, or would be if you had a default constructor that allowed it to be constructed without any arguments.

To construct an object you have to declare it:

```
VSL vsl(v, s);
```

But for a member variable it's already declared, so you can't do that in the constructor body.

If you had a default constructor you could update the variable in the constructor body, by assigning a new value to it:

```
vsl = VSL(v, s);
```

as long as your type has a correctly-written assignment operator.

Or you could initialize it  at the right time, in the constructor initializer list:

```
KVTest::KVTest(int argc, char *argv[])
:vsl( createVSL() )
{
}
```

This creates it as a copy of the object returned by `createVSL()`

```
VSL createVSL()
{
  vector<string> v;
  string s;
  VSL vsl(v, s);
  return vsl;
}
```